# Listing nested JSON data to table view

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have a complex nested JSON data as sown below:

```
[
{
    "class_name": "Class One",
    "section": [
        {
            "section": "A",
            "day": [
                {
                    "day_name": "Sunday",
                    "routine": [
                        {
                            "period": "First",
                            "teacher": "Kiran  Magar",
                            "start_time": "10:00 AM",
                            "end_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "subject": "English"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Second",
                            "teacher": "Kushal  Karki",
                            "start_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "end_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "subject": "Nepali"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Third",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "end_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fourth",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "12:30 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fifth",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "01:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "subject": "Grammer"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Sixth",
                            "teacher": "Madhu Sudhan Neupane",
                            "start_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "end_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "subject": "Nepali"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Seventh",
                            "teacher": "Puran  Duku",
                            "start_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "end_time": "03:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Computer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "day_name": "Monday",
                    "routine": [
                        {
                            "period": "First",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "10:00 AM",
                            "end_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Second",
                            "teacher": "Kushal  Karki",
                            "start_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "end_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "subject": "Nepali"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Third",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "end_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fourth",
                            "teacher": "Madhu Sudhan Neupane",
                            "start_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "12:30 PM",
                            "subject": "Science"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fifth",
                            "teacher": "Prasanna  Chudal",
                            "start_time": "01:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "subject": "Social"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Sixth",
                            "teacher": "Puran  Duku",
                            "start_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "end_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "subject": "Computer"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Seventh",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "end_time": "03:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "day_name": "Tuesday",
                    "routine": [
                        {
                            "period": "First",
                            "teacher": "Kiran  Magar",
                            "start_time": "10:00 AM",
                            "end_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "subject": "English"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Second",
                            "teacher": "Kushal  Karki",
                            "start_time": "10:40 AM",
                            "end_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "subject": "Nepali"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Third",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "11:20 AM",
                            "end_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fourth",
                            "teacher": "Madhu Sudhan Neupane",
                            "start_time": "12:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "12:30 PM",
                            "subject": "Science"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Fifth",
                            "teacher": "Prasanna  Chudal",
                            "start_time": "01:00 PM",
                            "end_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "subject": "Social"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Sixth",
                            "teacher": "Puran  Duku",
                            "start_time": "01:40 PM",
                            "end_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "subject": "Computer"
                        },
                        {
                            "period": "Seventh",
                            "teacher": "Komal  Rai",
                            "start_time": "02:20 PM",
                            "end_time": "03:00 PM",
                            "subject": "Math"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want to fetch the "day" which has "day_name" and then list the "routine" list accordingly as shown in picture below:

[image]

I have already made the table view cell design and linked all the property and also I have already made my struct as shown below:

[image]

I an stuck in the final function called (cellForRowAt)

Update:

I downloaded my JSON data using the function below :

```
    var dataRoutine = [RoutineDataModel]()

func downloadJsonData(completed : @escaping ()->()){

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.swipecrafts.com/class/routine")else {return}
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
    request.addValue("cf7ab8c9d4efae82b575eabd6bec76cbb86c6108391e036387f3dd5356a582171519367747000", forHTTPHeaderField: "api_key")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = httpBodyy.data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statuscode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if statuscode == 404{
                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Sorry! No Routine Found")
            }else{
                if error == nil{
                    do{
                       self.dataRoutine = try JSONDecoder().decode([RoutineDataModel].self, from: data!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completed()
                            print(self.dataRoutine.count)
                        }
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}.resume()

}
```

*Note : I am new to swift

Edit :

my response :

```
[Ez_Vidhya_School_App.RoutineDataModel(class_name: Optional("Class One"), section: [Ez_Vidhya_School_App.SectionDataModel(section: Optional("A"), day: [Ez_Vidhya_School_App.DayDataModel(day_name: Optional("Sunday"), routine: [Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("First"), teacher: Optional("Kiran  Magar"), start_time: Optional("10:00 AM"), end_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), subject: Optional("English")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Second"), teacher: Optional("Kushal  Karki"), start_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), end_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), subject: Optional("Nepali")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Third"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), end_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Math")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fourth"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("12:30 PM"), subject: Optional("Math")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fifth"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("01:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), subject: Optional("Grammer")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Sixth"), teacher: Optional("Madhu Sudhan Neupane"), start_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), end_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), subject: Optional("Nepali")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Seventh"), teacher: Optional("Puran  Duku"), start_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), end_time: Optional("03:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Computer"))]), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.DayDataModel(day_name: Optional("Monday"), routine: [Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("First"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("10:00 AM"), end_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), subject: Optional("Math")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Second"), teacher: Optional("Kushal  Karki"), start_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), end_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), subject: Optional("Nepali")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Third"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), end_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Math")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fourth"), teacher: Optional("Madhu Sudhan Neupane"), start_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("12:30 PM"), subject: Optional("Science")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fifth"), teacher: Optional("Prasanna  Chudal"), start_time: Optional("01:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), subject: Optional("Social")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Sixth"), teacher: Optional("Puran  Duku"), start_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), end_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), subject: Optional("Computer")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Seventh"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), end_time: Optional("03:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Math"))]), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.DayDataModel(day_name: Optional("Tuesday"), routine: [Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("First"), teacher: Optional("Kiran  Magar"), start_time: Optional("10:00 AM"), end_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), subject: Optional("English")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Second"), teacher: Optional("Kushal  Karki"), start_time: Optional("10:40 AM"), end_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), subject: Optional("Nepali")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Third"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("11:20 AM"), end_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Math")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fourth"), teacher: Optional("Madhu Sudhan Neupane"), start_time: Optional("12:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("12:30 PM"), subject: Optional("Science")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Fifth"), teacher: Optional("Prasanna  Chudal"), start_time: Optional("01:00 PM"), end_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), subject: Optional("Social")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Sixth"), teacher: Optional("Puran  Duku"), start_time: Optional("01:40 PM"), end_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), subject: Optional("Computer")), Ez_Vidhya_School_App.FinalRoutineDataModel(period: Optional("Seventh"), teacher: Optional("Komal  Rai"), start_time: Optional("02:20 PM"), end_time: Optional("03:00 PM"), subject: Optional("Math"))])])])]
```

Comment: You can link cell to specific label and then call the object class indexpath row wise to get data one by one. If u want suggestion please share some of you code with me in table View

Comment: Not related but you can declare all properties as non-optional (remove the question marks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this Output, you should create sectioned tableview with Headerview.

Implement Delegate methods like below.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrDayDataModel.count //In your case, this is the array of day from Section Data Model
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let dayModel = arrDayDataModel[section]
    return dayModel.routine.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

    let dayModel = arrDayDataModel[indexPath.section]
    let routineDayModel = dayModel.routine[indexPath.row]

    //Your Code goes here        
    cell.textLabel.text = routineDayModel.teacher
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let lblTemp = UILabel(frame: headerView.bounds)
    let dayModel = arrDayDataModel[indexPath.section] //Your FinalRouteDataModel
    lblTemp.text = dayModel.day_name

    headerView.addSubview(lblTemp)
    return headerView
}
```

FYI. Code will be changed as per your actual requirement, concept will be the same here.

Here `CustomCell` is your Custom table view Cell, let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: i have updated my code in question, can you please guide me accordingly

Comment: what is your json response? and what is                             print(self.dataRoutine.count)

Comment: My json response is at the end of my question, i have edited my question, can you please review it?

Comment: @TheSwiftGuy77 perfect response, try with the code I have provided, you have to think how you can implement, strategy is same with minor changes

Comment: I did with your code but i got stuck at this line "let dayModel = arrDayDataModel[indexPath.section]" , what does this "arrDayDataModel" variable refer to?

Comment: your sectionDayDataModel.day is the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167630/discussion-between-ppl-and-theswiftguy77).

Answer (score -1):

Try This code for swift 4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier : String = "periodCell";
        var cell : periodCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! periodCell ;
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = periodCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier);
        }           
        let periodData = arrPeriod.object(at: indexPath.row) as? FinalRoutineDataModel

        cell.lblPeriod.text = periodData!.period
        cell.lblTeacher.text = periodData!.reacher
        cell.lblStartTime.text = periodDa!ta.start_time
        cell.lblEndTime.text = periodData!.end_time
        cell.lblSubject.text = periodData!.subject

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: what does "arrPeriod" refer in "let periodData = arrPeriod.object(at: indexPath.row) as? FinalRoutineDataModel"  ?

Comment: please put some explanation regarding your code what is arrPeriod?